# Veto'ing files in Unix to allow *.PDF only

Tags: pdf, samba

Well, I have the following scenario:

- On my company there's a Samba shared folder `\\10.0.0.1\pdfsonly`;
- That folder is shared to everyone in the company and its purpose is to store scanned documents in PDF format;
- It is (at least) insecure to allow people to add any files there, so we thought to disallow adding files different from *.PDF there;
- On Samba, you can configure `veto files` parameters only to wildcards that will be prohibited.

So, our efforts let us to the following `veto files` config (some line breaks are included for better reading):

```
veto files = /*.a*/*.b*/*.c*/*.d*/*.e*/*.f*/*.g*/*.h*/*.i*/*.j*/*.k*
             /*.l*/*.m*/*.n*/*.o*/*.q*/*.r/*.s*/*.t*/*.u*/*.v*/*.w*
             /*.x*/*.y*/*.z*/*.0*/*.1*/*.2*/*.3*/*.4*/*.5*/*.6*/*.7*
             /*.8*/*.9*/*.pa*/*.pb*/*.pc*/*.pe*/*.pf*/*.pg*/*.ph*
             /*.pi*/*.pj*/*.pk*/*.pl*/*.pm*/*.pn*/*.po*/*.pp*/*.pq*
             /*.pr/*.ps*/*.pt*/*.pu*/*.pv*/*.pw*/*.px*/*.py*/*.pz*
             /*.p0*/*.p1*/*.p2*/*.p3*/*.p4*/*.p5*/*.p6*/*.p7*/*.p8*
             /*.p9*/*.pda*/*.pdb*/*.pdc*/*.pdd*/*.pde*/*.pdg*/*.pdh*
             /*.pdi*/*.pdj*/*.pdk*/*.pdl*/*.pdm*/*.pdn*/*.pdo*/*.pdp*
             /*.pdq*/*.pdr/*.pds*/*.pdt*/*.pdu*/*.pdv*/*.pdw*/*.pdx*
             /*.pdy*/*.pdz*/*.pd0*/*.pd1*/*.pd2*/*.pd3*/*.pd4*/*.pd5*
             /*.pd6*/*.pd7*/*.pd8*/*.pd9*/*.pdfa*/*.pdfb*/*.pdfc*/*.pdfd*
             /*.pdfe*/*.pdff/*.pdfg*/*.pdfh*/*.pdfi*/*.pdfj*/*.pdfk*
             /*.pdfl*/*.pdfm*/*.pdfn*/*.pdfo*/*.pdfp*/*.pdfq*/*.pdfr
             /*.pdfs*/*.pdft*/*.pdfu*/*.pdfv*/*.pdfw*/*.pdfx*/*.pdfy*
             /*.pdfz*/*.pdf0*/*.pdf1*/*.pdf2*/*.pdf3*/*.pdf4*/*.pdf5*
             /*.pdf6*/*.pdf7*/*.pdf8*/*.pdf9*/*.?/*.??
```

Summarizing, it disallow server to receive:

- Files with 1 or 2 characters on file extension;
- Files with extension beginning with [a-z] or [0-9], except with p;
- Files with extension beginning p, followed by [a-z] or [0-9], except by d;
- Files with extension beginning p, followed by d, followed by [a-z] or [0-9], except by f;
- Files with extension beginning p, followed by d, followed by f, followed by ([a-z] or [0-9]) and more characters.

But we have the following file types that we cannot block:

- Files without extension;
- Files extension beginning with "special characters" or with them following p or pd or pdf (not [a-z] nor [0-9]).

The following issues can occur if we use as is:

- No-superuser people can add PDF files without extension or with wrong extension, so other no-superuser people would not find or open the file;
- Malicious softwares/scripts/people can store files without extension or with wrong extension as part of some kind of attack.

So, help, please!

- To optimize current `veto files` config;
- To add configuration to disallow files without extension or with extensions different from *.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you say this is for storing scans - can you not just make it read only, give the scanner a user with read/write permissions and everyone would be happy?

> Files without extension;

There appears to be no documented way to accomplish this currently using samba's file veto'ing options. Amusingly, a "reverse veto files" feature was requested and on a 'to do' list... [11 years ago!](http://linux.samba.narkive.com/hELaUSfS/samba-reverse-veto-files#po%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bst3)

> Files extension beginning with "special characters" or with them following p or pd or pdf (not [a-z] nor [0-9]).

You'd likely need to escape these, by using a `\` before the special character. However, you really should instead look at telling the users not to do this type of thing.

A totally separate solution could be created using cron and a find statement, something along the lines of

`find -not -name "*.pdf" /directory -delete` which would delete all the files which don't end with `.pdf`.

Comment: About "can you not just make it read only, give the scanner a user with read/write permissions and everyone would be happy?", well, I did not tell about whole story :) We have two shared folders that will use that `\\10.0.0.1\pdfsonly` config: `\\10.0.0.1\scanneddocs` and `\\10.0.0.1\docsforasystem`. `scanneddocs` uses that config you said, but it is for general purpose PDFs. On `docsforasystem`, people will store in folders separated by subject some important files from `scanneddocs`, renamed and after some edit (rotate, OCR, delete pages, merge etc.).

Comment: About `special characters` issue, I am talking that *.pdf is accept as *.pd~, *.pd(, *.p¬), *.p@#, *.&*(, *._-_ etc.

Comment: The `*.` filter did not worked :( On that way, harry-potter-muggle-like-users would rename files deleting file extension and will not know how to open them :)

Comment: I think your problem is clearly the users, and not the system, you're going to be fighting them for a long time :(

Comment: Of course users are always the problem, elsewhere we would communicate through a command line browser now, because we are superusers ;)

Comment: An IT system is a way to avoid human errors. Skynet rules. Hasta la vista, baby.

Comment: We would really fight forever (both, our team and the issue) if we were Gold Saints. As I think we are not Athena Soldiers, the battle will have an end, someday :)

Comment: But we are interested in success. We tested /*./ with no effect. Perhaps it considers the punct character itself, as if it would be the last character of a filename, that we know in Windows it is impossible.

Comment: Since anyone else does not answer that question, I can assign your question as correct if A and (B or C): A. You erase that /*./ solution; B. You edit answer with definitive solution; C. You edit answer with "it is impossible" + perhaps some veto string optimization. The second part of your current answer is very interesting on the case there os impossible to edit veto string to match our needs.

Comment: I can't be sure it's impossible, but I'll remove the *. bit.

Comment: Amusingly, it was requested and on a 'to do' list... 11 years ago! - http://linux.samba.narkive.com/hELaUSfS/samba-reverse-veto-files#post3

Comment: I edited your answer adding your last comment :) On the future aliens will discover a frozen computer and will solve that.

Comment: @kokbira you can always request the change again, it may actually happen this time too ;)